# Regex to include decimals

Tags: regex

```
(\d+)[^0-9]+(\d+)[^1-9]+(\d+)
```

The above expression recognizes three consecutive groups of integers. How would it also recognize decimals?

for example:

```
234.34 x 455.44 x 455.33
```

the result:

```
(1) 234.34 (2)  455.44 (3) 455.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is allways 3 groups, use:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\D+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This will match 3 groups of float/integer.

**Expanation:**

```
(               # start group 1
    \d+         # 1 or more digits
    (?:         # start non capture group
        \.      # dot
        \d+     # 1 or more digits
    )?          # end group, optional
)               # end group 1
\D+             # 1 or more non digits
```

Same explanation for the rest of regex.

If you want to match only float (not integer), use: `(\d+\.\d+)\D+(\d+\.\d+)\D+(\d+\.\d+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UVUatA/1)

Comment: How would you recognize the first non-float/integer character

Comment: @Tee: Something like: `[^\d.+-]` that means NOT digit, dot, plus or minus. You can omit plus and minus if numbers are never signed.